# SQL Server Management Studio insert into nested select, invalid column

Tags: sql, sql-server

For some reason the year and month on this line:

```
(SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [YEAR], [MONTH]), [YEAR] , [MONTH])
```

are highlighted and saying "invalid column".

Am I doing something wrong? The "yearclass" contains both those columns. When I removed the nested select in the from and typed `from [dbo].[yearclass]` it worked, so I think there is something wrong with my nested function.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Time] 
     SELECT 
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [YEAR], [MONTH]), 
         [YEAR], [MONTH] 
     FROM
         (SELECT DISTINCT [YEAR], [MONTH] 
          FROM [dbo].[yearclass]));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like it should compile... you have one too many closing parentheses (`)`) and your `(SELECT DISTINCT...)` needs to have an alias like `(SELECT DISTINCT ...) AS x;`

Answer (score 1):

I think the right clause should be:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Time] 
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [YEAR], [MONTH]) , [YEAR] , [MONTH] 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [YEAR], [MONTH] 
        FROM [dbo].[yearclass]
    ) yearmonthclass;
```

There are two sintax errors in the query you gave us:

- an extra closing parenthesis (')')
- no name for the nested select

Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is, you are not having FROM clause in the subquery. The below code works fine in MSSQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE #YearMonth
(
yearvalue int,
monthvalue int
)

INSERT INTO #YearMonth
values(2018,1), (2017,1),(2016,1), (2018,1);


SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Yearvalue,Monthvalue), yearvalue, monthvalue from #YearMonth
```